# How do I make my Random generator of poker cards to end when cards are over?

Tags: java, android-studio, random, poker, playing-cards

Android version: 4.2

I am developing an android App. I need to generate images from drawable folder randomly and set the text to say which card is been selected.

I wish my app to enumerate every card randomly selected without repetitions
until the 52 card deck ends.

How could I achieve that?

My xml code is:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
```

In my drawable I have 52 images of poker cards with different names.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ImageView imageView;

   TextView txt1;

   Button button;

   Random r;

   Integer[] images = {
           R.drawable.ace_of_hearts,
           R.drawable.two_of_hearts,
           R.drawable.three_of_hearts,
           R.drawable.four_of_hearts,
           ...
```

I am using this code to generate random cards on button click and display card name.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    r = new Random();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //remove duplicates
            do {
                pickedImage = r.nextInt(images.length);
            } while (pickedImage == lastPicked);


            lastPicked = pickedImage;
            //display random image
            imageView.setImageResource(images[pickedImage]);
            txt1.setText(images[pickedImage]);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I wish my app to enumerate every card randomly selected without repetitons until the 52 card deck ends.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: There are probably many ways to do that. You could simply put 52 card objects into a list and shuffle that list. And please note that "please help me solving this problem" isn't regarded as real question here. We help you making your steps, we don't do them for you.

Comment: If you use a random number generator to pick the cards, you cannot guarantee that each of the cards will eventually be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of choosing a random card and then having to deal with duplicates, an easier approach may be to shuffle the array and then just present an image from there:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    List<Integer> shuffledCards = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(images));
    Collections.shuffle(shuffledCards);
    final Iterator<Integer> iter= shuffledCards.iterator();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Stop once all the cards have been displayed
            if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                return;
            }

            image = iter.next();
            imageView.setImageResource(image);
            txt1.setText(image);
        }
    });
}
```